# How do I add the zf2 library as a submodule

Tags: git, zend-framework2, git-submodules

I want to add the [ZF2](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/release-2.3.1/library/Zend) library as a submodule. Not the whole repos, just the library/Zend folder with the required classes.

My (desired) folder structure

- myproject (git root)

  - public
  - app
  - lib

    - Zend (add the submodule here)

      - Authentication
      - Barcode
      - .... and so on.
    - Future modules to come

I followed [this](http://kshmakov.org/notes/th/2/) example.

```
$ cd myproject
$ git submodule add https://github.com/zendframework/zf2.git lib/Zend
$ cd lib/Zend
$ git config core.sparsecheckout truen
$ echo library/Zend > ../../.git/modules/lib/Zend/info/sparse-checkout
$ git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

But Zend is located in: `myproject/lib/Zend/library/Zend(/Authentication and-so-on)`

What can I do to remap this?

Comment: Do you change the Zend code and you need to track these changes? If not, maybe it is a better idea to download dependencies like Zend with Composer? https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: I don't change the Zend code. I just want an easy way to update to future ZF2 versions. Can composer do that?

Comment: And this is exactly what dependency managers are created for.

Comment: I'll look into it, but leave the question open. I'm still curious if there is a git way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Wojciech Frącz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878514/wojciech-fr%C4%85cz) suggested I ended up using Composer.